# Not able to capture click event on Netflix seek bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onclicklistener, reverse-engineering, netflix

I have a chrome extension that relies on detecting click event on seek bar of Netflix. The div ([data-uia=timeline-bar]) is added dynamically to dom once user hovers over the video player, so I tried to use event bubbling to listen to the event.

```
    //after injecting jquery on page 
    $('body').on('click','[data-uia=timeline-bar]',function(e){
        console.log('click detected');
    })
```

It didn't work out so I tried to add listener at capture phase. All click events are being detected but the seek bar click.

```
document.addEventListener('click',
(e) => {console.log('click detected during capture phase')}
,true);
```

Is there a way to listen to the click event on ([data-uia=timeline-bar])?

[image: Netflix screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem. Can't you add listener because it's dynamically removed and added?

Comment: I don't have control over the netflix dom, however I can inject some code in the page. I tried attaching listener to it but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your goal needs hard work, as dom elements are created and deleted permanently. The only approach I can propose can certainly be considered as dirty, but you can try it at least ;)

```
$("[data-uia='player']").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
    const ref = "div[data-uia='timeline-knob']";

    if($(ref)){
        $(ref).off("mouseover").on("mouseover", function(event){
            const that = $(this);
            const previousSibling = event.target.previousSibling;

            if(previousSibling.style.left){
                console.log("Click presumed");
            }
            else {
                console.log("released");
            }
        });
    };
});
```

The trick is to observe the timeline-knob object, and analyse the situation upon the previous sibling div, because some repaints occur when the mouse is over the timeline.

It's just a workaround, I hope this can help you :) Have a nice day !

[EDIT 1]

A more elegant way :

```
const ref = "div[data-uia='timeline'].active";
const onclick = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked on", e);
};
const prepare = (obj, e) => {
    $(e.target).css("pointer-events","auto").css("border", "0.1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0)");
    $(obj).off("click.test").on("click.test", (clickevent) => {onclick(clickevent.target);});
};

$("[data-uia='player']").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(modevent){
    $(ref).each(() => {
        prepare(ref,modevent);
    });
});
```

I had to face several difficulties :

1. even the "timeline" node is regenerated, so we to attach the "click" event to it at each "player" modification
2. basically, we often have to click on empty divs (for example exactly on the timeline), and then no "click" event is fired, so we apply an almost invisible layout to it to force the browser consider it as a clickable node.
3. and not the least one : Netflix uses the "pointer-events" css property to some block "click" events, so we have to fix it back to "auto"

I tested this code several times and it **seems** working fine ;)

Comment: Wow! this is interesting. The code works  when user clicks on seek bar but clicks are missed if you click slightly above or below the seekbar. Let me try if I can modify the code to achieve the result. https://imgur.com/vEPNEG9

Comment: I am also curious how you figured it out? timeline-knob seems to be small ui element visually. How mouseover is working on it across the seekbar.

Comment: Hi @Terminal ! In fact, the mouse over event event is a direct consequence of the fact that the user clicks exactly on the seekbar. In that case, the knob sticks onto the cursor and then the mouseover event occurs ^^ Then when can check the DOM changes there where made by Netflix at the user click.

Comment: Understood! In the meantime, I tried this code to handle clicks nearby seek but doesn't seem to work https://codepen.io/t3rminal/pen/xxrjNPw

Comment: Let me see if I can patch it ;)

Comment: @Terminal, I propose you another approach, certainly perfectible. I have edited my answer

Comment: That is great. Who are you Philippe. Would like to connect with you. How do you even figure these things out? With elements constantly going in and out of dom, the process is even harder. Did you manage to freeze that somehow and then debug? And what is "click.test"? Let me just play around with the code a bit.

Comment: Glad to read it :) Me ? Just an obstinate French guy ^^ I spent a lot of time observing the live dom modifications, and groping... About the .something notation on events, it's only a namespace to be sure you address the right one when you unbind it.

Comment: Netflix is copying the added style to other elements too. Although that can be handled but in some peculiar cases (achieved by hovering seekbar in & out few times) it is ignoring the hover on seekbar and clicking on it triggers play/pause event. Anyway I will explore this option further to handle glitches. Thanks a lot for your solutions.

Comment: Here comes your bounty :) If you don't mind connecting, please drop a 'Hi' on piyush.neo@gmail.com.

Comment: Many thanks for this huge reward ! I learned many things while looking for an acceptable solution, thanks for this challenge. I contact you soon, if you don't mind my "french style" with the English language :D

Answer (score 2):

Add a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to the parent of the [data-uia=timeline-bar] element that observes when its children changes e.g. timeline-bar is added? and in the callback you attach a listener once the timeline-bar element is added?

```
// The timeline-bar's parent's data-uia is "timeline" in the Netflix player DOM.

let parent = document.querySelector("[data-uia=timeline]"),
    options = {
      childList: true
    },
    observer = new MutationObserver(mCallback);

observer.observe(parent, options);

function mCallback (mutations) {
  for (let mutation of mutations) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') { 
      for(let node of mutation.addedNodes){
        if(node.getAttribute("data-uia") === "timeline-bar"){
           node.addEventListener('click', () => {
             alert("clicked");
            // Do click stuff...
           });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// To test the observer
btnAttr.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let el = document.createElement("div");
  el.setAttribute("data-uia", "timeline-bar");
  el.innerText = "A TIMELINE-BAR";
  parent.appendChild(el);
}, false);
```

codepen here: https://codepen.io/freedruk/pen/powaKBy

Comment: I was trying to avoid the mutation observer route initially but what ever works now. Is this working on Netflix? I tested in console but it is not working with Netflix player.  I believe data-uia=timeline itself is dynamically added. Let me try changing the classes. FYI you don't need a separate test. True test will be if that works on Netflix player.

Comment: I have edited your code to target the right dom elememts. The parent to attach observer shouldn't be dynamic. The click event is triggered some times and missed other times. See if you can figure out anything else https://codepen.io/t3rminal/pen/RwgMzQd